# How i get response data from api url usinf fetch in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am hitting login.php with POST method and two parameters. In response it will return a status and message parameter but i am not getting response from login.php. I want to console this message *"Username or Password is wrong."*. If i console "response" it returns this:

```
body: ReadableStream { locked: false ...}
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers { <prototype>... }
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost/reactjs/example1/code/login.php"
<prototype>: ResponsePrototype { clone: clone(), arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer(), blob: blob(), … }
```

My code is:

```
const payload = {
            username: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password

        }
 fetch(`/reactjs/example1/code/login.php`, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(payload),
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                console.log(response);

            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

login.php :

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

if(isset($obj->username) && !empty($obj->username)  && isset($obj->password) && !empty($obj->password) ){

        if($obj->username == 'spatel@bamko.net' && $obj->password == '123456'){
                $result = array('status'=> 1, 'username'=> 'spatel@bamko.net' );
        }else{

            $result = array('status'=> 0, 'message'=> 'Username or Password is wrong.' );
        }
}else{

        $result = array('status'=> 0, 'message'=> 'Username or Password is blank.' );
}       



    echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Where is the React code?

Comment: Your response body is not used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are getting getting `arrayBuffer` in response.

Can you try below code:-

```
fetch(`/reactjs/example1/code/login.php`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  }).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
  .then(function(buffer) {
    console.log(buffer)
  });
```

If you want `json` output we usually do

```
res => res.json()
```

Comment: In your case - response, I have changed variable name.